# Next number in Sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

What is the next number in the sequence:  `1 4 23 25 26 ?`

Also, could you answer the logic that goes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next number is:

> 28

Method:

I plugged the numbers into hexadecimal to text convertor and found the following sequence: `#%&`. I found this interesting because on my keyboard, it's the shift position for the values 3, 5, and 7 on a computer.

[image]

Therefore, the next logical step is Shift-9, or (. The full correct sequence is `#%&(`, and `(` in hex is the number we need.

I think the 1 and 4 are red herrings, or just cool because today I learned about SOH and EOT.

Comment: You surely rock!

Comment: Oh snap, my first solved puzzle! Thank you :D

Comment: Well this just does not work here in the U.K. as $23$ would need to be $A3$. It also wont work for standard keyboards in France, Germany, Italy, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, or Finland - not to mention any of the countries outside of Europe, some of which are quite large like China, India, Russia and Brazil.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's true. I guess the original questionnaire had to be more clear with the question. Otherwise, I guess based on what he thought was right, I solved the puzzle

Answer (score 7):

The next number is

> 91

Because it is

> The closest integer value of the polynom. 
>  $2.04 x^4 - 25.9 x^3 + 112.4 x^2 - 183.5  x + 96$
>  for x=6, the previous numbers being the values from 1 to 5

Comment: Wow! There must be a simpler way than that.

Comment: @NickilMaveli in case you didn't realize, fffred is not really seriously suggesting this as an answer...

Comment: There should be a special markup for sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

This was a trick question.

> There are no other numbers in the sequence

...because

> All the numbers in the sequence are the solutions to the equation $x^5-79 x^4+2197 x^3-24361 x^2+82042 x-59800 = 0$ and there are only 5 of them.

Comment: Boom. Solid answer. Clearly it's the only correct answer, it should be accepted already. XD

Comment: @Reti43. You forgot to use the "sarcasm" markup in your comment.

Comment: @Marius I think that XD counts as <sarcasm>